# creating a dictionary from array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array like this:

```
(
    "ALAsset - Type:Photo, URLs:assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=EF015EF6-FC98-4ACF-9092-AF7E0196A760&ext=JPG",
    "ALAsset - Type:Photo, URLs:assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=6FC0C2DC-69BB-4FAD-9709-63E03182BEE1&ext=JPG",
    "ALAsset - Type:Photo, URLs:assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=324E4377-0BCD-431C-8A57-535BC0FC44EB&ext=JPG"
)
```

And am having a hard time figuring out how to create a dictionary/mutable dictionary that will have a key of "urlRep" and also "caption" for each object in the array.

So I want my dictionary to look like this:

```
(
{
urlRep = 
    "ALAsset - Type:Photo, URLs:assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=EF015EF6-FC98-4ACF-9092-AF7E0196A760&ext=JPG",
caption = ""
},

{
urlRep = 
    "ALAsset - Type:Photo, URLs:assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=6FC0C2DC-69BB-4FAD-9709-63E03182BEE1&ext=JPG",
caption = ""
}

)
```

sorry if my formatting is off but that is the basic idea of what Im going for but am failing to achieve

Comment: This is pretty elementary stuff. What code do you have so far?

Comment: Note that you do not (I hope) want your dictionary to look like that, you want your array of dictionaries to look like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
NSMutableArray *otherArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSString *string in myArray)
{
    [otherArray addObject:@{@"urlRep":string, @"caption":@""}];
}
```

You are creating another array with a nsdictionary on every entry.

If you want to edit the caption for example for the dictionary at position 0:

```
[[otherArray objectAtIndex:0] setObject:@"myValue" forKey:@"caption"];
```

But you will have to create them as NSMutableDictionary then.

Comment: Perfect, this is what I was looking for. With this `otherArray` whats the best way to edit what caption is equal to?